# Библиотека для создания геоинформационных систем на платформе .NET, C#

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, гис

Привет! Перед мною встала задача реализации геоинформационной системы для отображения состояния устройств, расположенных на местности. Нужно реализовать функции добавления устройств на карту и программно изменять внешний вид в зависимости от данных с этих устройств. А также обрабатывать нажатие на устройство на карте. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хорошую библиотеку для создания ГИС для платформе .NET. Спасибо !)

Comment: Можете попробовать Open Street Map https://github.com/OsmSharp/core

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать ОСМ, но если требования по количеству пользователей картой будет не большое, то лучше попробовать google map API.

Отправной точкой может послужить [вот этот проект](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36151/Show-Your-Data-on-Google-Map-using-C-and-JavaScrip) или вот этот [тутор](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRoAjs8RwfE), если делать нужно на винформ.

Агрегировать данные с девайсов нужно будет делать самим, скорее всего. Необходимо будет развернуть базу данных (mySql или на худой конец Sql Lite пойдут) и написать клиент и сервер для обмена геоточками.

При обработке точки, сервер сохраняет её в базу с id девайса. После можно будет это все отправлять на google map, при желании можно будет даже маршрут рисовать, как, например, [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263106/draw-path-between-points-google-map-in-asp-net).

К слову, у меня есть на гитхабе старенький [проект](https://github.com/mikhail-efremov/Xamarin.Android.MobileTracker) на xamarin, реализующий клиент и умеющий находить позицию, отправлять по UDP на сервер, сохранять позицию в локальную базу и отрисовывать карту точками из базы на дейвасе.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент, по моему мнению, наилучший вариант это [mapwindow](http://www.mapwindow.org/)

Есть ocx компонент самой карты, позволяющая грузить туда что угодно - стандартные типы данных, а так же любые другие через GDAL. Есть пример GIS системы, написанной на C# с использованием ocx компонента. И есть библиотека dotStatial позволяющая работать с пространственными данными.

Есть ещё SharpMap и MapAround, но они не сильно развиваются в данный момент.

Так же стоит освоить библиотеку GDAL, которая в обязательном порядке используется всеми ГИС-приложениями.