# какие карты использовать?

Tags: c#, карты

Нужно для проекта выбрать наиболее удобные и красивые api/библиотеки карт, которые можно всунуть на форму (WPF/winforms) C#. 
рассматривали 2gis, но получается, что нужно запускать WebBrowser и некоторые функции как клик не работают. Именно карты, которые можно сделать без WebBrowser и которые будут красиво смотреться

нам нужно расставить поинты на них, приближать, удалять, строить маршрут

Comment: я вообще не в теме, но за 10 секунд нагуглил [это](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps), может вам поможет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Библиотека для создания геоинформационных систем на платформе .NET, C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741454/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5-net-c)

Comment: Что понимать под удобными и красивыми api/библиотеками?